# TextInput is displaying the value react native

Tags: react-native

Hi in my `componentWillMount` I set my states like this

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.timeSheetData().then((timeSheetResponse)=>{
        this.setState({comments:timeSheetResponse.comments});
        this.setState({spentHours:parseInt(timeSheetResponse.hours)});
        alert(this.state.spentHours);

    });
});
```

In my view

I have the `TextInput` like this. I can't display the value on the `TextInput` but I can display the value on Text I don't know why it's happening

```
<TextInput keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(spentHours) =>this.setState({spentHours})} 
                   value={this.state.spentHours} />
```

Comment: spentHours should be a key. when you set the state, you should set it as this.setState({spentHours: spentHours})

Comment: @JanFranzPalngipang thats just shorthand in es6 - take a look here: http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand. If the var name is the same as the key it can be used like this :)

Comment: I got the the answer. I have to use string for displaying the value in TextInput

Answer (score 1):

Input values need to be strings so you either need to remove `parseInt` in your `componentWillMount` method:

`this.setState({ spentHours: timeSheetResponse.hours });`

or in your template you need to convert the input value to a string with `toString()`:

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='numeric'
  onChangeText={spentHours => this.setState({ spentHours })} 
  value={this.state.spentHours.toString()}
/>
```